# How to solve the error "appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' does not exist or is not accessible" in testing an Android app using Appium?

Tags: android, appium

I am testing an Android app using Appium with UiAutomator2. I think I have set up everything correctly.

However, when I run the index.js using "node index.js" command, I get the following error message in console output:

> *Request failed due to An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The file at '/home/heyn/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk' does not exist or is not accessible*

Full console output:

https://gist.github.com/HeynSekk/e5fc76dc7d975569f8d18d54dcd00974

Full Server log output is as the following:

https://gist.github.com/HeynSekk/fb03a762d65b0366f2849af52ab5046a

How can I solve this error?

Environment

-Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

-Appium v1.16.0

-Automation: UiAutomator2

Comment: hey, did you resolve issue? how?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is very clear, it says that there is no such file (appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk) in path `home/heyn/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/`. You need to provide correct path to your application to start appium server.